# why code snippet in stack overflow did not support the css property height if value is in percentage

Tags: support, feature-request, design, stack-snippets, product-support

This is my doubt since started to use the code snippet,the code snippet didn't take the css property  `height` if value is in percentage.i added the code below.

```css
aside {
width:50px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<aside>
 </aside>
```

but it will display `width` even if value is in percentage .i'm added code of that too.

```css
aside {
width:100%;
 height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<aside>
</aside>
```

is there any alternatives i can use  instead of `height:100%;` in code snippet ,because that is a great factor in responsive design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do but **as with all HTML** the 100% has to have something to relate to. Usually this is the `html` or `body` elements.

```css
aside {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<aside>
</aside>
```

Comment: tnx...this should help me